# Make a loop with (forEach, map,...) until length of object (children) is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I want to set the active element to false in all of the objects. This is my object:

```
const obj = 
  { name: 'obj1'
  , ative: true
  , children: 
    [ { name: 'obj2'
      , ative: true
      , children: 
        [ { name: 'Obj23'
          , ative: true
          , children: [...] 
      } ] } 
    , { name: 'obj3'
      , children: 
        [ { name: 'Obj32'
          , ative: true
          , children: [...] 
      } ] } 
    , ...
    }
```

what I have to is, for the main object `obj1` and all of the childrens, and sub childres.
I want to set the `active` to `false`.
The point is, I don't know how many childrens there can be under each child. I would have to create some type of loop with a `map` or something of the kind.
I will need to stop looping when the children is equal to 0 (no length)

EDIT: All solutions where really awesome. Thanks

Comment: `ative` !== `active`. Besides that I would say that a recursive function will do the job: call it for the main object and the function will then call itself for each child that it finds. 3 lines of code...

Comment: The most efficient way in terms of time complexity would be an iterative approach using stack. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3v0AN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: (continued) I wouldn't recommend using `map` or `forEach`, since to actually be able to use those we would have to manipulate the length of the array, which is really a side effect. Alternatively, you could use recursive approach, however recursive approach takes more memory, since every invocation of the function requires some space in call stack

Comment: @wonderflame that will make the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) with [`reviver function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#the_reviver_parameter) to do this:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value ) => key === 'ative' ? false : value );
```

```js
const obj = {
    name: 'obj1',
    ative: true,
    children: [{
        name: 'obj2',
        ative: true,
        children: [{
            name: 'Obj23',
            ative: true,
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        name: 'obj3',
        children: [{
            name: 'Obj32',
            ative: true,
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => key === 'ative' ? false : value);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Pretty neat trick!

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches that can be used

1. Iterative approach
2. Recursive approach

In most cases, the iterative approach is better in both memory and speed since the recursive approach requires `O(n)` extra memory for each invocation in the call stack.

In the iterative approach `map`, and `forEach` array methods will be useless, since we don't know the length and when to stop, even if manage to use them it will require us to mutate the traversed array which leads to side-effects. Instead, we are going to use a simple `while` loop.

Algorithm:

- Create a stack array and put the input object in it
- While stack is not empty

  - Let current be the popped element from the stack
  - Set current's `active` to `false`
  - Add current's children into stack to traverse its children
- Return item (optional, since we are mutating the input object)

Implementation:

First, let's create a type for the input data structure:

```
type Item = {
  name: string;
  active?: boolean;
  children: Item[];
};
```

Now, the function itself:

```
const setActive = (data: Item): Item => {
  const stack = [data];

  while (stack.length) {
    const current = stack.pop();

    if (!current) continue;

    current.active = false;

    stack.push(...current.children);
  }

  return data;
};
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3v0AN)

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with wonderflame that a stack-based approach is better if you don't know how large your tree will grow, but if you know you will only ever go a few levels deep then the optimization might not be needed, and a recursive approach is simpler.

```js
function deactiveRecursive(obj) {

  return {
    ...obj,
    active: false,
    children: obj.children.map(child => deactivateRecursive(child));
  };
}
```